# Is it right way to create sinlgeton class by weak_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, singleton

I create a parent class to handle singleton pattern with smart pointer:

.h file:

```
template<class singleType>
class Singleton
{
public:
    static std::shared_ptr<singleType> GetInstance();

private:
    static std::weak_ptr<singleType> m_singleObject;
};
```

.cpp file:

```
template<class singleType>
std::shared_ptr<singleType> Singleton<singleType>::GetInstance()
{
    auto shareObject = m_singleObject.Lock();
    if (!shareObject)
    {
        shareObject.reset(new singleType);
        m_singleObject = shareObject;
    }

    return shareObject;
}
```

Not sure it is the right way to use smart pointer?
Any idea?

Many Thanks

Comment: So is the basic idea that once all pointers to the singleton are out of scope then the singleton gets deleted. Then later when you need a pointer to the singleton once again you create a new singleton? If that is the case it looks good. Haven't tried it, but everything looks right.

Comment: ... my imagination about singletons is they shouldn't `delete` while the program is alive. Isn't it?

Comment: @MM. Pretty often, yes. Sometimes it is also "There can only be none, or one, but never more."

Comment: The "right" way to create a singleton? Who told you such a thing is possible? The right thing is to not create a singleton.

Comment: @jalf: Sudden influx of singleton questions. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pros and cons of this implementation are already discussed. But there are a bunch of bugs:

1) As this is a template you have to move your implementation into the header or the linker cannot find it.

2) The `.lock()` function of the weak_ptr is not in capitals.

3) Don't forget to instantiate

```
template<class singleType> 
std::weak_ptr<singleType> Singleton<singleType>::m_singleObject;
```

4) Better use `shareObject = std::make_shared<singleType>(singleType());` instead of the `new`:  http://herbsutter.com/gotw/_103/

5) As Konrad mentioned: it's not thread-safe.

Comment: Thanks Gerrit, only about point 2, std::weak_ptr function is .Lock(). boost is .lock().

Comment: @MarkGuo I only tried it with Clang and libc++. There its .lock(). And see here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr

Comment: Using make_shared would not work if you make your constructor private. (which I think you should for a singleton)

Answer (score 4):

I did some research so now I'll post an answer.

The code all looks like it should work and is a correct usage of smart pointers. The only question is how exactly you want the singleton to behave. This should behave like a textbook singleton EXCEPT for the behavior that if nothing currently has a pointer to the singleton, it will delete itself. This behavior is something that really depends on the implementation of your program. If you want the singelton to only exist when it is in use, then I'd say go for it.

I would just avoid creating and destroying the singelton too often especially if the construction and deconstruction are particularly intensive. If it is constantly getting created and deleted then you are probably better off with a more standard singleton implementation. The standard singleton behavior tends to be that a singleton is only created once during the duration of the program running and is never deleted.

I think this is a clever implementation given you have a use for it and I might have to borrow the idea.

Comment: It is strange idea to delete and then recreate (if needed) a single object! It is not smart having singleton in the first place but you try to make it even worse.

Comment: I don't want to argue the merits of singletons, but I could see this method being useful especially if the singleton is not used often, and the singleton has a particularly large memory footprint. In a lot of cases they are a bad idea, but in others they are very useful and would be difficult to write code without.

Comment: It a problem to test the code with singleton but this particular implementation makes it almost impossible.

Comment: I still argue it depends on exactly how and where they are used, but I think we will have to agree to disagree.

Answer (score 4):

Your code isn’t thread safe.

The name `lock` may suggest that concurrent access is blocked but in fact there’s no such guarantee: when multiple threads concurrently call your `GetInstance` function you will get several instances instead of guaranteeing a single one.

You need to create an explicit lock for the whole duration of the `GetInstance` function’s lifetime. Note that this is of course not very efficient.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge this should be fine. You'll avoid out of order destruction issues, but it could be a problem to create new instances after your initial instance is created. This singleton will have only one instance alive at any time, but over the course of the program running more than one instance may have been alive overall.

This destruction and recreation may also be unwanted in terms of performance, not only in side-effects.